# How to select the same field twice with different conditions and display results as separate fields

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

**I want to create a Table Adapter in C# as follows.**

I wish to use same filed in a table twice with different conditions, and it must be shown as two different fields.

Here are my source tables:

[image]

From the `AttendanceReg` table I need to `Count` each of the student's records based on `AttendStatus` to find the number of days they were `Absent and present` based on `course and month`.

> Sample Query:

```sql
Select  AttendanceReg.StudentID
      , AttendanceReg.Studname
      , AttendanceReg.StudSex
      , AttendanceReg.StudCourse
      , Count(AttendanceReg.AttendStatus) As Total_Present
      , DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) As Month
From    (AttendanceReg
         Inner Join LocalTable
            On AttendanceReg.StudCourse = LocalTable.AttendCourse
               And DatePart('M', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) = LocalTable.AttentMonth
        )
Where   (AttendanceReg.AttendStatus = 'Present')
Group By AttendanceReg.StudentID
      , AttendanceReg.Studname
      , AttendanceReg.StudSex
      , AttendanceReg.StudCourse
      , DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance)
Order By DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) Desc
```

> Query results and desired results (The first image shows what I'm getting, and the second image says what I actually want):

[image]

What do I need to do?

- Note : I need to use the `LocalTable`, I can't pass in arguments to specify `Course` and `Month`

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT A.StudentID, A.Studname, A.StudSex, A.StudCourse, 
SUM(CASE WHEN A.AttendStatus = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalPresent,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.AttendStatus = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalAbsent
FROM AttendanceReg A 
INNER JOIN LocalTable L ON A.StudCourse = L.AttendCourse AND DatePart('M', A.DateOfAttendance) = L.AttentMonth)

GROUP BY A.StudentID, A.Studname, A.StudSex, A.StudCourse
```

Comment: While Executing This giving an error ..Unable to parse query text.The query cannot be represented graphically in the Diagram and Criteria Pane.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Access Database 2010 and i think "CASE WHEN" is not supported by access database

Comment: SELECT StudentID,Studname,StudSex,StudCourse,
 
SUM(IIf(AttendStatus = 'Present', 1,0)) AS TotalPresent,

SUM(IIf(AttendStatus = 'Absent', 1,0)) AS TotalAbsent

FROM AttendanceReg

GROUP BY StudentID,Studname,StudSex,StudCourse

This is working almost...now how to how i can use where condition to this query?

Comment: You can add where query before group by clause

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have Solved This Issue, Thanks To @Ikram Turgunbaev :)

> Here Is the Code

```
SELECT AttendanceReg.StudentID,AttendanceReg.Studname, AttendanceReg.StudSex,
AttendanceReg.StudCourse,
SUM(IIf( AttendanceReg.AttendStatus = 'Present', 1,0)) AS TotalPresent,
SUM(IIf( AttendanceReg.AttendStatus = 'Absent', 1,0)) AS TotalAbsent, 
DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) AS MYMONTH

FROM (AttendanceReg
    INNER JOIN LocalTable ON
    AttendanceReg.StudCourse = LocalTable.AttendCourse 
    AND 
    DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) = LocalTable.AttentMonth)

GROUP BY AttendanceReg.StudentID, AttendanceReg.Studname,
    AttendanceReg.StudSex, AttendanceReg.StudCourse,
    DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance)

ORDER BY DatePart('m', AttendanceReg.DateOfAttendance) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Same thing Can also be done using Switch :)

```
SELECT EmpAttendance.EmpID, EmpAttendance.Empname, EmpAttendance.EmpSex, EmpAttendance.EmpDepartment, EmpProfileTBL.Salary, 
SUM(SWITCH(EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Present', 1, EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Absent', 0, EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Half-Day', 0)) AS TotalPresent,
SUM(SWITCH(EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Absent', 1, EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Present', 0, EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Half-Day', 0)) AS TotalAbsent,
SUM(SWITCH(EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Half-Day', 1, EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Present', 0, EmpAttendance.AttendStatus = 'Absent', 0)) AS HalfDay,

DatePart('m', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance) AS CurMonth,
((EmpProfileTBL.Salary * TotalPresent) - (EmpProfileTBL.Salary * TotalAbsent) 
                         + ((EmpProfileTBL.Salary / 2) * HalfDay)) AS FinalSalary
FROM ((EmpAttendance INNER JOIN LocalVariableTable
ON EmpAttendance.EmpDepartment = LocalVariableTable.TempDepartment AND
DatePart('m', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance) = LocalVariableTable.TempMonth
 AND DatePart('yyyy', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance) = LocalVariableTable.TempYear)
INNER JOIN
EmpProfileTBL ON EmpAttendance.EmpID = EmpProfileTBL.EmpID)

GROUP BY EmpAttendance.EmpID, EmpAttendance.Empname, EmpAttendance.EmpSex,
EmpAttendance.EmpDepartment, DatePart('m', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance), 
EmpProfileTBL.Salary
ORDER BY DatePart('m', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance) DESC
```