# How to join two queries with more than 1 joins - SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I need to create a `Table Adapter` in C# using the query below. I am using an MS Access database in my program.

I am not able to use `IIF`, `Switch`, `Case` directly in the Select query instead of joining this two query, because Visual Studio Table Adapter does not support it.

See this question written by me - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888400/error-in-list-of-function-arguments-not-recognized-unable-to-parse-query-t)

I tried my level best to do this simply. But none of them helped me.

Actually this is what i want to do - [How to select the same field twice with different conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837386/how-to-select-the-same-field-twice-with-different-conditions-and-display-results)

**Query - 1**:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Present, t2.Absent
FROM
   (SELECT  
        EmpID, COUNT(*) AS Present
    FROM 
        EmpAttendance
    WHERE 
        AttendStatus = 'Present'
    GROUP BY 
        EmpID) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         EmpID, COUNT(*) AS Absent
     FROM 
         EmpAttendance
     WHERE 
         AttendStatus = 'Absent'
     GROUP BY 
         EmpID) t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID
```

**Query - 2**:

```
SELECT 
    EmpAttendance.EmpID,
    EmpAttendance.Empname,
    EmpAttendance.EmpSex,
    EmpAttendance.EmpDepartment,
    EmpProfileTBL.Salary
FROM 
    ((EmpAttendance
INNER JOIN 
    LocalVariableTable ON EmpAttendance.EmpDepartment                       = LocalVariableTable.TempDepartment
                       AND DATEPART('m', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance) = LocalVariableTable.TempMonth
                       AND DATEPART('yyyy', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance) = LocalVariableTable.TempYear)
INNER JOIN 
    EmpProfileTBL ON EmpAttendance.EmpID = EmpProfileTBL.EmpID)
GROUP BY 
    EmpAttendance.EmpID,
    EmpAttendance.Empname,
    EmpAttendance.EmpSex,
    EmpAttendance.EmpDepartment,
    DATEPART('m', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance),
    EmpProfileTBL.Salary
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART('m', EmpAttendance.DateOfAttendance) DESC
```

I need To merge these two queries. How to do this?

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags; please tag with the database you are really using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Describe the logic of what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: I have Mentioned All the Things that you want..please check two links that i have provided

Comment: this is what I want as an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837386/how-to-select-the-same-field-twice-with-different-conditions-and-display-results

Comment: The query design window in MS Access is very helpful. I appreciate that English may not be your first language, but "this is what I want as an answer" is not appropriate for SO.